# What is the Monerodo Operating System?

Tags: full-node, operating-system

What is the [Monerodo Operating System](http://nodebox.link/) (Monerodo OS)? What is its relationship to Monero, and how safe is it?

Answer (score 10):

The Monerodo OS (sometimes referred to as MOS, at least, in the system itself) is a text-user interface and customized Ubuntu Linux distribution that is maintained and developed by Gingeropolous (and yes, that's me). The operating system is designed to give individuals with no Linux knowledge the ability to operate a fully dedicated node device in their home using any spare hardware available at minimal cost (because they don't have to buy a new operating system).

Monerodo is a portmanteau of the word Monero and the esperanto word for node, "nodo".

There is no official relationship to Monero core team and it is only as safe as the Ubuntu operating system on which it is built.

Answer (score 5):

It's a version of Ubuntu that is loaded with a suite of software that allows you to run a node, mining pool, wallet, as well as be a hub for all your devices/computers to connect to. It's intended to be used online, and still somewhat basic. The idea is to make it easier for users to get up and running with Monero without the need for too much in depth knowledge, or spending ages trying to setup everything.

Gingeropolous is fairly well known in the Monero space, though he himself has also said that he shouldn't be trusted either. I think the only real danger would be if someone tried to repackage Gingeropolous' Monerodo OS with scamware.